# Changes cannot be made to Pen because permissions are not valid

Tags: c#, winforms

```
m.pen = Pens.Red; //No error

m.pen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Square;        //error
```

Where m is an object of another class which holding the Pen as global.

While i am trying to set endcap or startcap it shows me the error as

"Changes cannot be made to Pen because permissions are not valid."

Anyone Know How to Rectify This.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pen object returned by [Pens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pens%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are immutable, meaning their properties cannot be changed. Try creating an object of Pen.

```
Pen pen =new Pen(Color.Red,20f);
pen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Square;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
m.pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pens.Red is a static member initialize by the framework, and you can't modify it.

You must declare your own Pen like this :

```
m.pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
m.pen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Square;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to get this exception is **disposing a** `Pen` **object created from the** `Pens` **class.** Consider this:

```
Pen pen = Pens.Red;
// Use the pen object here...
pen.Dispose(); // throws the same exception
```

If you want to dispose your `pen` object then -again- create it via the `Pen` constructor like

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
```